# Activitynotfoundexception error..Getting nowhere

Tags: java, android

I have seen all the posts on the subject but sadly since I am a beginer, I just cannot relate any solution given for those post with that of mine.
Hence I am putting my code below so that you could provide me customized reply..

I am trying to launch an application here on my phone.A button as been provided which when pressed should execute the startactivity

I am attaching the files below for reference

```
package com.mycompany.myapp3;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

addListenerOnbutton();


    }

public void addListenerOnbutton() {

button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){
Intent intent = new Intent("com.xyz.speed");


startActivity(intent);


}
});


}
}
```

Next is manifestfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp3" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



05-18 19:02:41.987 9919 9919 E     SELinux                                      [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
05-18 19:02:41.987 9919 9919 I     art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-18 19:02:42.007 9919 9919 D     TimaKeyStoreProvider                         in addTimaSignatureService
05-18 19:02:42.017 9919 9919 D     TimaKeyStoreProvider                         TimaSignature is unavailable
05-18 19:02:42.017 9919 9919 D     ActivityThread                               Added TimaKesytore provider
05-18 19:02:42.057 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
05-18 19:02:42.057 9919 9919 W     ResourcesManager                             getTopLevelResources: com.mycompany.myapp3 for user  0
05-18 19:02:42.067 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             Inside getClassLibPath caller
05-18 19:02:42.087 9919 9919 D     InjectionManager                             InjectionManager
05-18 19:02:42.087 9919 9919 D     InjectionManager                             fillFeatureStoreMap com.mycompany.myapp3
05-18 19:02:42.087 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             Constructor com.mycompany.myapp3, Feature store :{}
05-18 19:02:42.087 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             featureStore :{}
05-18 19:02:42.117 9919 9919 W     ResourcesManager                             getTopLevelResources: com.mycompany.myapp3 for user  0
05-18 19:02:42.127 9919 9919 D     DisplayManager                               DisplayManager()
05-18 19:02:42.127 9919 9919 W     ResourcesManager                             getTopLevelResources: com.mycompany.myapp3 for user  0
05-18 19:02:42.157 9919 9919 D     PhoneWindow                                  *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
05-18 19:02:42.157 9919 9919 D     PhoneWindow                                  *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
05-18 19:02:42.167 9919 9919 D     Activity                                     performCreate Call Injection manager
05-18 19:02:42.177 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.mycompany.myapp3.MainActivity isFragment :false
05-18 19:02:42.197 9919 9948 D     OpenGLRenderer                               Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-18 19:02:42.217 9919 9919 D     PhoneWindow                                  *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
05-18 19:02:42.217 9919 9919 D     PhoneWindow                                  *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
05-18 19:02:42.257 9919 9948 D     libEGL                                       loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
05-18 19:02:42.297 9919 9948 I     OpenGLRenderer                               Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-18 19:02:42.307 9919 9948 D     OpenGLRenderer                               Enabling debug mode 0
05-18 19:02:42.307 9919 9948 D     mali_winsys                                  new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
05-18 19:02:42.317 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.mycompany.myapp3.MainActivity
05-18 19:02:42.317 9919 9919 I     InjectionManager                             dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.mycompany.myapp3.MainActivity
05-18 19:02:42.507 9919 9919 I     Timeline                                     Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@49f2b0d time:38707264
05-18 19:02:43.557 9919 9919 D     ViewRootImpl                                 ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-18 19:02:43.667 9919 9919 D     Instrumentation                              checkStartActivityResult  :Intent { act=com.xyz.speed }
05-18 19:02:43.667 9919 9919 D     Instrumentation                              checkStartActivityResult  inent is instance of inent:
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 D     AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.mycompany.myapp3, PID: 9919
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.rma.myspeed }
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1815)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1513)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3933)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3881)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4204)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4172)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.myapp3.MainActivity$100000000.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-18 19:02:43.677 9919 9919 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
```

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: There is no activity set up to respond to the `com.rma.myspeed` action. What book are you using that suggested that you use `Intent intent = new Intent("com.xyz.speed")` to start the activity?

Comment: Follow the instructions here carefully: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: What is the name of the activity you want to start? `"com.xyz.speed"` is a string, not an Activity?

Comment: com.xyz.speed is the package name of the app which i am trying to launch... How do i construct an activity.. Sorry I am feeling dumb here

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to register every Activity you want to use in your app in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
....>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

....

    <activity android:name="com.example.ExampleActivity"/>
```

After your register it you can execute it.

Start Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```